# Transfer keystore from Adobe Air to Unity

Tags: keystore, android-keystore

Hope all is well.

We moved a game from Adobe Air to Unity.

But I have issues signing the new Unity game on Google Play.

Do you know how we can move signature / keystore from Adobe Air (p12) to unity (keystore)?

Your help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

hjeko

We tried different ways to sign the unity game but we always get rejected.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to change your existing .p12 to .jks in order to use it. For this you will need the java keytool (this is part of your Java SDK).

Then launch your terminal and use this:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore [MY_FILE.p12] -srcstoretype pkcs12
 -srcalias [ALIAS_SRC] -destkeystore [MY_KEYSTORE.jks]
 -deststoretype jks -deststorepass [PASSWORD_JKS] -destalias [ALIAS_DEST]
```

MY_FILE.p12 is your existing .p12 file

MY_KEYSTORE.jks is the destination path where the new file will be saved.

PASSWORD_JKS is your new password for the generated keystore

ALIAS_SRC this should be the same as the current name of your p12

ALIAS_DEST this should be the same as the keystore name.

I hope this works for you.

EDIT:

If you dont have the alias of your keystore you can use this simpler version:

```
keytool -importkeystore  -srckeystore [MY_FILE.p12] -destkeystore [MY_KEYSTORE.jks] -srcstoretype PKCS12
-deststoretype jks -deststorepass [PASSWORD_JKS]
```

I have tested on one of my p12 files and it works as should.

Comment: Hello @leossmith Thank you for your response. My dev tried it and it did not work. Do you think you could do this task? I can pay for it. Thank you for your help! JM

Comment: Hi @Jean-MarieTruelle I am guessing you had an issue with the alias? Please try the simpler command.

Comment: Hello @leossmith thank you for your response. Do you think this is a task you could do? I can pay for it. You can contact me at contact@oneconnectionmedia.com Thank you! JM